# Variables not remembered after it is assigned to another variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

I have bash script which is calling from different services, While that call it will transfer two variables into this bash script. Well that is perfectly printed with the same variables

```
#!/bin/sh
template=`cat <<TEMPLATE
***** Test *****
Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE
APP: $SERVICEDESC
Server: $HOSTALIAS
TEMPLATE
`
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "$template"
```

But When i try to extract the variables property by following I'm getting empty

```
#!/bin/sh
template=`cat <<TEMPLATE
***** Test *****
Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE
APP: $SERVICEDESC
Server: $HOSTALIAS
TEMPLATE
`
echo $SERVICEDESC > /tmp/ser
echo $HOSTALIAS > /tmp/ho
SerID=$(cat /root/apps.properties | grep "^$SERVICEDESC" | cut -d'=' -f2);
HosID=$(cat /root/apps.properties | grep "^$HOSTALIAS" | cut -d'=' -f2);
echo $SerID > /tmp/serid
echo $HosID > /tmp/host
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "$template"
```

All `$SerID`,`$HosID`,`$SERVICEDESC`,`$HOSTALIAS` these were empty. But `$template` prints perfectly.

`app.properties` has the following APP and Server ID:

```
app1=5
server1=6
app2=6
server2=7
```

I'll match the `$SERVICEDESC` and `$HOSTALIAS` from this `app.properties`, and fetch the Number and store it to `$SerID` and `$HosID`

`$SERVICEDESC` or `$HOSTALIAS` weren't declared because, these values will be obtained by another service or application which is usually calling this script to print the output template. But I need to extract the values for these metioned variable to start another process

Can you please help me out to fix this.

Comment: Where are you setting `$SERVICEDESC` and `$HOSTALIAS`?

Comment: @Kusalananda This script is called from different services and that will assign the values for these variables

Comment: Are the variable exported (environment variables)?  Also, when you say that `$template` "prints perfectly", does that mean that `$SERVICEDESC` and `$HOSTALIAS` are expanded to the correct values? Also note that we can't see your `/root/apps.properties` so we can't say why `$SerID` and `$HosID` are empty.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes $SERVICEDESC and $HOSTALIAS got the correct values inside, But when i try print it or get values it is empty outside of `

Comment: What does `$SERVICEDESC` and `$HOSTALIAS` contain when you start your script?

Comment: Is any of your files a DOS text file, or does the the values of you variables contain carriage-return characters at the end?

Comment: @roaima this is additional script which is calling by one of applications. That application will send the values to $SERVICEDESC and $HOSTALIAS.

Comment: Unless you tell us what the values are for `$SERVICEDESC` and `$HOSTALIAS`, we can't help confirm that they will match in your `app.properties` file.

Comment: The values for $SERVICEDESC will be app1 or app2 and $HOSTALIAS will be server1 or server2. Right now the values not getting beyond the template declared.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `$SERVICEDESC` or `$HOSTALIAS` so they won't have any values.

Furthermore, you then try to use them to obtain values for `$SerID` and `$HosID`, which in turn means they don't match anything.

---

Some comments

1. If it's a `bash` script, start it with `#!/bin/bash`. What you have there at the moment is a bourne shell script (`sh`).
2. Replace the template assignment with this

   ```
   template="***** Test *****
   Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE
   APP: $SERVICEDESC
   Server: $HOSTALIAS
   TEMPLATE
   "
   ```

Comment: yes, $SERVICEDESC or $HOSTALIAS weren't declared because, these values will be obtained by another service or application which is usually calling this script to print the output template. But I need to extract the values for these metioned variable to start another process

Comment: I have added the app.properties in the post again. And I have tried our the solution still it is same. Outside of Quotation (" ") the values remains empty